# After canceling a job with the IPP protocol, the job's completed page count cannot be retrieved using the 'get-job-attribute' operation

Tags: printing, cancellation, intel-ipp

I use cancel-job Ipp operation to cancel a processing job.The printer need some time to stop the current job printing.It will print some pages before stopped.The job status is canceled and job-impressions-completed count is not change after using get-job-attribute.But I cannot get the exact count that this job print.

I want to get the job's output count when using cancel-job to get the job canceled.